# button color change by tab key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and I want it to change to green when I access it by tab key. I have written the code for hover by mouse but I want that when a user a goes to the button using tab key then it should change the color.

Comment: please post you have so far

Comment: What have you tried so far? and can you post some code for us to have a look at

Comment: I think you need something like focus event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the `:focus` pseudo selector

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/L2u9mxng/)

```
button:focus{
    color:green;
}
```

[**More on `:focus` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class is applied when a element has received
>   focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or
>   by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).

You may also wish to give the `button` a [**`tabindex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/tabindex) attribute to control its tab order.

Comment: Can you please tell that when I focus by tab key it does changes its color but after pressing enter it remains green but I want its color to be original which was red... how to achieve that??

Comment: @abhi, change the `:active` pseudo selector with `color:red`

Comment: @abhi- it does: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/L2u9mxng/1/ dont forget, after a button press, the button still has focus.

Comment: @abhi - I may be mistaking you saying `press enter` for `clicking` - if that is the case, you will need to use Javascript, you may want to post a new question for that part

Comment: yes thats what I want is that after button press to remove focus